# Update UI bootstrap cannot add new suggestions to Typeahead

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to update the typeahead suggestions on the fly. The typeahead does not reflect the changes on the array it is bound to. How do I fix that? I'm using ui bootstrap

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hghesteemed/8wnyuj98/10/) replication, add value, try typing it in the tyeahead, no update

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $log, $uibModal) {

    $scope.addName = function() {
        console.log("adding name" , $scope.name);
        $scope.fieldNames.push($scope.name);
    }

    $scope.fieldNames = [{name:"Paul"},{name:"Pamela"}, {name:"Adam"}, {name:"Atrium"}];
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things

1. you are pushing a string into the array, you should push an object with a name property instead
2. you have a limit filter on the ng-repeat limiting your visible suggestions, you may want to remove it, or at least icrease it

instead of

```
$scope.addName = function() {
    console.log("adding name" , $scope.name);
    $scope.fieldNames.push($scope.name);
}
```

do

```
$scope.addName = function(newName) { // <-- passing the $scope.name from the template
    console.log("adding name" , newName);
    $scope.fieldNames.push({ name: newName});
}
```

and edit

```
uib-typeahead="field as field.name for field in fieldNames | limitTo:4 | filter:{name:$viewValue}"
```

to

```
uib-typeahead="field as field.name for field in fieldNames | filter:{name:$viewValue}"
```

[Here is an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wnyuj98/11/)

Comment: Thanks, my bad...inserted string, works fine after mod